# Dynamically validate the email if it exists in the database using angular JS custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using angular js validation in the form. I wanted to perform a email exists in the database or not dynamically.

I have gone though some custom directives to acheive it. I dont able to do it correctly. Though server is giving webservice response with the email as exists or not.

Please help me on angular js validation based on webservice json response from server using custom directive to validate dynamically.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Check this: http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/form-validation-the-angularjs-way/#100-custom-validation-through-custom-directives

Comment: Written by developer that was big part of upgrading how validation is done in angular http://www.yearofmoo.com/2014/09/taming-forms-in-angularjs-1-3.html

Comment: Thanks both of you!! I will try this out and come back here if i have any doubts ..

Comment: I tried both the things. I can able to see the ajax call to server perfectly. But its not throwing an error after the json back to UI eventhough if the server returns or not. Its always going on success part.